# Guard in c++, destructor not called when the exception is not treated in main

Tags: c++, exception, guard, raii

If we consider the following code with g++ or clang, the destructor of the Guard class is not called when the exception is not catched at least in the main function. I made a thew googling, and did not find any usefull information.

I use guard class at lot to implement RAII. Thus, I found this to be quite disapointing, in particular when dealing with ressources such as semaphore.

I though that C++ requires the destructor to be called when an exception is thrown. Is this behaviour standard or is this du to the libstdc++ implementation ?

Thank you for any help or advice in this matter.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

struct Guard
{
  Guard()
    : v(new int)
  {
    std::cout << "Guard()" << std::endl;
  }
  ~Guard(){
    std::cout << "~Guard()" << std::endl;
    delete v;
  }
private:
  int *v;
};

void test(){
  auto g = std::make_shared<Guard>();
  throw("youch");
}

void test2(){
  test();
}


int main(void){
  // try{
    test2(); 
  // } catch(...){

  // }
  return 0;
}
```

P.S. : I do not wish to add a try/catch block in the main function as I appreciate to be able to trace back an exception to the point where it is emitted in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with implementation defined behavior.  Per the standard **[except.handle]**

> If no matching handler is found, the function `std::terminate()` is called; whether or not the stack is unwound before this call to `std::terminate()` is implementation-defined

So `g` may or may not be destroyed based on what implementation you are using.  You will not be able to rely on this always being handled the same way.

Comment: Thank you for this precise answer.  I must say that this undefined behaviour is pretty frustrating. Indeed, I was not aware that one have to set an exception handler to be sure that  RAII does work in all cases.